# Can community users log in from the normal login page?

Tags: community

Can community users log in from a community other than the custom login page?

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question title, no, community users cannot login via login.salesforce.com or test.salesforce.com. They must login using a community URL. This can point (or be re-directed) to a "standard" community login page (from the template) or a customized one.

With Salesforce, platform users have to have a username that is unique across all Salesforce orgs. However, community users sharing the same username can exist across many communities. It is for this reason that community users can only login using a community login page.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a login page for communities and use it as an entry point.
If you are referring to getting to communities after login into salesforce, then you can enable the banner so from the top banner users can select the community to login

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is No. Community users are logged in via special url's created for the community which can be any organzsation domain specific or default salesforce generated force.com subdomain.